# Show default selection in Select dropdown - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here is my code:

```
<select label="people" id="ppl"  [(ngModel)]="Selectedppl" (ngModelChange)="onPplSelection($event.target.value)">
<option>select people</option>
<option *ngFor="let x of peopleList" [ngValue]="x">
    {{x.name}}
</option>
```

Since people list is an object with name, address, contact. I want to send object as params to ngModelChange with ngValue.

But, once I selected a particular people and saved.I want the dropdown to be changed as the selected people name. Basically, I want to 
show the default selected option in dropdown once saved.

Am not using Reactiveforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can have the reference of element and pass its value to function.

```
<select label="people" id="ppl" #ppl="ngModel"  
   [(ngModel)]="Selectedppl" 
   [compareWith]="compareFn"
   (ngModelChange)="onPplSelection(ppl.value)">
     <option>select people</option>
     <option *ngFor="let x of peopleList" [ngValue]="x">
       {{x.name}}
     </option>
</select>
```

### ts

If you have complex object then you must ue compareFn which help Angular to compare the object to set the default value.

```
  compareFn(a, b) {
    if (!a || !b) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return a.name === b.name;
    }
  }
```

Working copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-2z9f3b

Comment: I tried your solution. But this is not setting default selection option. Can you show any demo as how this works.

Comment: Added the `compareWith` directive, it should solve your problem. See the updated answer.

Comment: Am able to get the selected value in console & also some span tag in html but it is not showing the selected option only inside select tag.

Comment: what is the value of `Selectedppl` you are passing as `ngModel` of select ?

Comment: entire object of people with name, address, and contact in ngModel

Comment: Please create stackblitz demo for easy and quick fix.

Comment: updated the answer with woring link https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-2z9f3b